# Something starts mysqld on my Mac, and I don't know what it is

Tags: mysql

Occasionally, I notice my M1 MBP getting hot, and `mysqld` using 100% of the CPU.

I don't know that I installed `mysqld`, certainly I don't need it for work, not directly.

I run PyCharm, WebStorm, Docker, Firefox, and iTerm, but I don't need the MySql database (not even in a docker container).

I used `Activity Monitor` to figure out what's the parent process, thinking it might help me figure out what spawned it, but it's `launchd`.

Any idea how I can figure out if something actually need it? And if not, how to get rid of it?

On a related note, it's running on Rosetta, and not Apple arch.

Thanks!

Comment: Kill it and see who starts complaining ;) - or connect to it and see what other clients connect and what queries they run.

Comment: I kill it every time I see it go beserk, but nothing crashes or complains! I don't know if I can connect to it, I would have no idea of the credentials needed.

Comment: you could try just running `mysql -u root` or `sudo mysql -u root`, that might work without a password if it is configured the right way, or the password might be somewhere in the logs

Comment: If you can get connected, do `SHOW DATABASES;`.  The names of the databases may give you some more clues.

Comment: Or you can check the datadir to see what directories are there (they correspond to the databases too).